# How to set a spacing parameter in customized list?

Tags: spacing, itemize, line-spacing, enumitem

I am using the following code to generate my own list:

```
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet}
```

and am not sure how to introduce a spacing parameter there, like something along the lines of

```
\setlength
```

Could someone help me define a global length parameter here?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to obtain. Lists use many spacing parameters, which are more easily handled with the `enumitem` package.

Comment: I wish to alter the spacing between individual items. I am using this list because I wish to use the bullet points whereas the standard would be dashes. However, I am wondering if in that custom-defined environment, one can also integrate a command that pins down the spacing? Thank you so much @Bernard

Comment: You would use `\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet,topsep=1ex,itemsep=1em,partopsep=.5ex,...}` and whatever you can find in the vertical list spacing elements of [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Comment: If you want a smaller vertical spacing than the default, you can use `\setlist[mylist]{noitemsep}` or even  `\setlist[mylist]{nosep}`.

Comment: @Werner your comment sounds like it could be turned into an answer. Would you like to provide it? Otherwise, I think we could close this as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Done... it remains vague.

Comment: @Werner upvoted. At least it's no longer in the unanaswered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use

```
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet,topsep=1ex,itemsep=1em,partopsep=.5ex,...}
```

(no `\setlength` macros) and whatever you can find in the horizontal/vertical list spacing elements of [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).